# How to say "generating errors" in one word?

Tags: word-choice

Erroneous means containing errors. I wanted to say about files that generate errors in a computer program, so I posted on a public mailing list: *errogenous files*. Could it be better? By better I don't mean more amusing.

Maybe the construct I used is correct, but unfortunate. Is it? Actually you won't find any "errogenous files" on the net except those of mine :)

> The program scans files, and the files in question contain characters
>   which trigger error messages in the scanning program.

Comment: One word? I cannot think of any. Error-triggering files would be my suggestion

Comment: Those are two words connected by a hyphen. Might as well say error-generating then...

Comment: "Problem files" is one term I've seen used. I wouldn't say they generate the errors though, they demonstrate the existence of errors in the code.

Comment: _Problem files_, sounds good. And _error-triggering_ too.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, goodness, no, don't use *errogenous*.  For one, it's [not a word](http://www.onelook.com/?w=errogenous&ls=a).  For another, even if you wanted to invent a term, your candidate would be a homophone of *[erogenous](http://www.wordnik.com/words/erogenous)*, and I don't think that's what you want to convey.

I'd recommend a hyphenated term: something like *error-generating files.*

Answer (score 2):

I've used the term **problematic files** (or more generally, **problematic input/data**) in similar cases. Terms like *edge case*, *unexpected input* or *random input* are somewhat related but stray from the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: This might work, depending on the context.  If the O.P. is alluding to real-world files that cause problems, then I'm in hearty agreement. If the O.P. is alluding to deliberately-constructed diabolical files used for testing, however, not so much.  (It was hard to tell which, from the limited contextual information provided, until the recent edit.)

Answer (score 1):

The files aren't producing errors--the program is. A few word suggestions: "mishandled files," "test cases," "bug reproducers," or "minimal examples" (if the files are edited down).